# Error on line 9 char 2 "The Property Department cannot be found

Tags: powershell

This script should take user input for an Department name in DC and change it to a new one.
But for some reason the error that I get comes at line: 9. It sees that it cant find "Department".
This is the error I get:

Exception setting "Department": "The property 'Department' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At line:9 char:2

```
`$oldDepartment = Read-Host "Old Department Here"

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {Department -eq $oldDepartment} -SearchBase "DC=company,DC=com" -   Properties Department | 
Select-Object $oldDepartment

$newDepartment = Read-Host "New Department Here"

$users | ForEach-Object {
$_.Department = $newDepartment
Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -Replace @{Department = $newDepartment}
}

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {Department -eq $oldDepartment} -SearchBase "DC=company,DC=com" -   Properties Department

$users | Format-table Name, Department`
```

Comment: Remove `| Select-Object $oldDepartment` from `$users = Get-ADUser ...`

Answer (score 0):

-PassThru can be used to return the user you just updated, though I'm not sure if it'll include the new Department value.

Anyway, I feel like this kind of thing is a good fit for the pipeline:

```
$oldDepartment = Read-Host 'Old Department Here'
$newDepartment = Read-Host 'New Department Here'

$users = Get-ADUser -Filter {Department -eq $oldDepartment} -SearchBase 'DC=company,DC=com' -Properties Department -OutVariable updatedUsers | 
    Set-ADUser -Replace @{Department = $newDepartment } -PassThru |
        Format-Table Name, Department

#uncomment this if needed
#$updatedUsers | Get-ADUser | Format-Table Name, Department
```